# Parallel Payment through mobile native app

Tags: mobile, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, stripe-payments

I am trying to find a parallel payment implementation for my mobile app, where the payment should happen with in my application and not redirected to any browser.

I have seen few options like paypal parallel payment, but this doesn't provide native app purchase support.

Can some one please point me to right direction. I am wondering am I only one trying for this option? :)

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ramesh.V

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an API payment gateway rather than a checkout page solution. There are numerous services such as [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api), [BrainTree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/developers), [BlueSnap](http://www.bluesnap.com/ecommerce/api) and even [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro) that offer this.
The reason this is not popular for apps is that you'll need to become PCI compliant for that, which is a pain. Non of the above services will grant you access to the API without it, but they will be happy to give you a checkout page (browser) to drop the PCI compliance requirement.
I've successfully used a service called [Zooz](http://www.zooz.com/) for my mobile checkout and it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can goto www.zwitch.co . This is an Indian payment startup which offers in-app payment natively.They have mobile SDK with which you can accept payments in your app.You can design your own payment page.They say you will be reduced from the PCI Scope